# How to create isolated Vuex states for every initialized instance of a component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue.

I see people suggest that we need to use a Vuex module for components to store their state data so we can access that data in the parent component.

For example, I have MarkdownEditor.vue component and I'll need to access its data from the parent. I store the state in a Vuex module, e.g markdownEditorStore.js... I can access this state in the parent component easily, like, `this.$store.state.markdownEditor.XYZ`.

That's OK. But what if I have n number of MarkdownEditor components and need isolated states for each of them? This is very basic problem, but how can I handle this?

I need a solution based on instances of module, not a module based one.

Comment: You need to identify instances somehow. An index in state array or some form of uid. This could be XY problem, people could suggest anything, but this doesn't mean it fits your case. If there's a direct parent-child relation and data isn't used anywhere else, it would be more straightforward to just use Vue events as usual

Comment: @EstusFlask Let's say I created a UUID for each instance of a child component, in its created() method. How can I access that child component's UUID in the parent to get the child's data from the vuex state? Only way to get the UUID of the instance is to create and pass the UUID while initiating that component in the parent? This looks dirty to me. That UUID generation could be in child's code imo, but don't know how. And then how could I get that UUID in that case? Questions...but don't know the answer.

Comment: This would defy the purpose. If you're able to pass id from a child to a parent, you could pass the rest of data as well. Since you're already tied to the store, you could make it hold the logic for id, i.e. have getEditorId `getter` function. Making it `action` wouldn't be good, afaik actions can return random data but it's always wrapped with a promise, and I'm not sure it's allowed.

Comment: I.e. in your case it would be `this.childEditorId = store.getters.getEditorId(); store.dispatch('createEditor', this.childEditorId)` or `this.childEditorId = await store.dispatch('createEditor')`, and the first way is less straightforward but more conventional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module feature is to split the logic between different domains(Editor in your case is one module). Not for the instances themselves.

The rule of thumb is that the parent that will connect with the Vuex store passes down to MarkdownEditor.vue the data necessary to load. Ideally, MarkdownEditor is able to load just with the props received from the parent. This is a good practice of splitting the visual from the state. Making it easier to test and a clear component API.

Even though you have N possible ME(MarkdownEditor) instances, either you show one at once or multiple. For both cases, you can have a MarkdownEditorDataStore that will hold all the data needed.

Then you just need to access the correct piece of data for each ME instance. And that's up to your store and components structure. Two ways I can think of is that either you have an array for the N ME instance like `editors: [ { id: 1, title: X}, { id: 2, title: Y } ]` or an object that holds all the data `{ editors: { 1: {id: 1, title: X }, 2: { id: 2, title: Y } }`.

Either you get the data via `this.$store.state.MarkdownEditorDataStore.editors[myID]`
or
`this.$store.state.MarkdownEditorDataStore.editors.find(id => myID === id)`

You can have a data property holding the `currentEditorId` in case you show just one instance at a time. Even better to use a getter in that case to show the `actualCurrentEditorObject`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's clear that you got me absolutely right. So the only way to accomplish this "ID" way is to create that ID in the parent and pass it to the child component? Could we move the code which generates the ID of the child to the child component's itself and still access it in the parent?

Comment: There's not just one way to do it, it's up to you and what you need to accomplish your goals. The ID could be created when a new editor is added and you assign that ID, not necessarily in the component, could it be also in the store via an action for example. What looks to me is that you need to figure out where to split your state logic from your component logic. The component itself doesn't need to create an ID unless it makes sense for this component. But the ID here seems to be valuable just to keep track of your instances and then more valuable to the store.

Comment: Ok thanks this helped me overcome my confusion

Answer (score 1):

What i understand from your question is that you want a individual state for each component which you can achieve by creating a separate module with namespace=true
for each component
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Not actually. Namespacing is a module-level solution. I'm asking about an instance level solution (E.g initiated instances of a module, or separate states for each instance of a component / its state). Thanks btw.

Comment: @oyrinkozhi You can create a module dynamically for each instance. Depends on the complexity a state if it's feasible.